# Vuetify scrolling issue

Tags: asynchronous, vue.js, vue-router, vuetify.js

I'm trying to add links in my navbar that go to a section of page using Vuetifys scrolling, here's my code:

```js
pageClicked (page) {
  this.goToPage(page.path)
  this.goToTarget(page, this.options)
},
goToPage (path) {
  this.$router.push(path)
},
goToTarget (target, options) {
  if (target.topOfPage) {
    this.$vuetify.goTo(0, options)
  } else if (target.id) {
    this.$vuetify.goTo(target.id, options)
  }
}
```

Problem is the scroll fails if I'm not on the same page that where I'm scrolling to is on cause it can't find the target id because it hasn't loaded yet. How can I ensure the page has fully loaded before trying to scroll to the section?

Comment: if not in current page, use `gotoPage` first with your target ID, then call goToTarget() when mounted that page.

Comment: How can I wait til the page is mounted before goToTarget() is called?

Comment: Within that page, hook mounted, then get params = targetID from the Vue Router, then call `gotoTarget(targetID)`

Comment: Nothing is being mounted sometimes